# How can we dealloc the view that we are no longer use it any more?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I am currently design a simple application which the user should login first.

I set the login page as the root view of the window. Once the user login the system, it will modal present a tabbar view.

I guess the login pages (which are actually several view controllers in navigation controller)   are useless after then. Can I dealloc those pages and reset the root view as the tabbar controller?

Comment: If you use pushViewControllers you only need to pop them. Do not call dealloc from your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the Login page as the root. Presenting a modal view with a tab bar that should now act as the root is the wrong way, and most likely be rejected by Apple for this.

The second view you currently have, or the view the user should see AFTER logging in should be the root. In this root view, check to see if the user is logged in, if not, present the login as the modal view.

Comment: I assume you what you mean is setting the tabbar as the rootView and adding code in ViewWillAppear Method to check if the user is logging in. Why can't I set the login page as the rootView? What's the drawback of it?

Comment: Why can't I set the login page as the rootView? What's the drawback of it?

Comment: The draw back would be the login view being the root view controller. This is not a standard or even correct way of handling a login view. The way I described would be the correct way.

Comment: Should I need to implement the viewWillAppear in the first viewController in the tabbarController?

Answer (score 0):

You should never call `dealloc` directly from your code. With no ARC, the only exception is calling `dealloc` for the super class. With ARC (and you should use ARC), you don't have to call `dealloc` anymore.

That being said, since the login screen is only going to be needed in a few runs, why don't invert the flow, and make the tabbar controller the root of your app, and only when it is needed present the login view, perhaps without animation, so the user will never see the root?